# Calling smart contract function with web3: this._eth.call is not a function

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

i went throught the greeter example in here https://www.ethereum.org/greeter and i deployed the smart contract under ropsten test net.

Now im trying to call it from a web page using web3.

```
var greeterAddress = '0xbc15fCDef6F6FAbAd4097816006523626c10a685';
        var abi = [{ constant: false, inputs: [], name: 'kill', outputs: [], type: 'function' }, { constant: true, inputs: [], name: 'greet', outputs: [{ name: '', type: 'string' }], type: 'function' }, { inputs: [{ name: '_greeting', type: 'string' }], type: 'constructor' }];
        
        var greeter2 = new web3.eth.contract(abi).at(greeterAddress);        
        
        console.log('Calling the smart contract');
        var result = greeter2.greet();
        console.log(result);
```

i keep getting while calling:

```
var result = greeter2.greet();
```

the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._eth.call is not a function
    at c.call (inpage.js:14300)
    at c.execute (inpage.js:14300)
    at send (ex.html:32)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (ex.html:14)
```

which step should i take to make sure the contract doen't have any initilization problem?
For what i have seen by looking around at examples this should work without problems.

More info: I have another piece of code sending ETH to an address and works just fine, so web3 should be properly installed (version is 0.2x.x.)

**EDIT Final working solution:**

```
 var greeterAddress = '0xbc15fCDef6F6FAbAd4097816006523626c10a685';
        var abi = [{ constant: false, inputs: [], name: 'kill', outputs: [], type: 'function' }, { constant: true, inputs: [], name: 'greet', outputs: [{ name: '', type: 'string' }], type: 'function' }, { inputs: [{ name: '_greeting', type: 'string' }], type: 'constructor' }];
        
        var greeter2 = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(greeterAddress);        
        
        console.log('Calling the smart contract');
        greeter2.greet(function (error, result) {
            if (!error)
                console.log(result)
            else
                console.error(error);
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your function `greet()` has either `constant`, either `view` or `pure` access modifier. You can not `call` function that can modify contract data.

**UPDATE:**
Another suggestion: try not to use `new` keyword while binding the contract. Just do

```
var greeter2 = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(greeterAddress);
```

Comment: the function should be alright is this one:
      function greet() constant returns (string) {
        return greeting;
    }

Comment: also trying to call that same function in https://remix.ethereum.org/ seems to work fine as well

Comment: @user1964154 take a look at update

Comment: this worked, i just edited with the working solution on my starter message, thank you for the assistance